# Another .htaccess redirect case

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site where mydomain.com and mydomain.com/frontpage serves the exact same content.
Socalled SEO experts tell me it is very bad to have the same content on different addresses. Google will cast upon me a terrible fate.

So I thought fine, I'll just redirect mydomain.com to mydomain.com/frontpage, but I'm failing miserably. I just can't wrap my head around htaccess commands.

I need to have visitors who visits mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com to be redirected to www.mydomain.com/frontpage in a way to that it becomes visible in the browser address field.
BUT nothing else must be redirected.
For example, www.mydomain.com/anotherpage must still be there.

My .htaccess is already full of a lot of rewrite rules that redirects all of these user-friendly addresses to the real urls (index.php?pageid=341) etc. So I'm thinking I would first redirect mydomain.com to mydomain.com/frontpage and then let another RewriteRule later make sure that mydomain.com/frontpage actually points to index.php?pageid=341.
But mydomain.com => mydomain.com/frontpage must be a visible redirect, while all the other rewrite rules are hidden from the user.

How does the `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` or `RewriteRule` look like, that redirects visitors from www.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/frontpage while keeping other addresses like e.g. www.mydomain.com/anotherpage ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert this new rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /frontpage [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. It almost works. But it keeps the rest of the url too for some reason. The address becomes mydomain.com/frontpage/?pageid=431. I've managed to produce this result myself. :-/

Comment: You need to keep this rule as very first rule after `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread it. I placed it above the `RewriteEngine On` line. Yes, it works now! Thank you very much!